# Exclude folder from dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

Is it possible to define the directory exclusion for the dependency in maven?

I have a dependency defined in pom.xml. When compiled, this dependency is added into META-INF/lib. The problem is, the library contains about 40 MB of XML files I do not need, so I want to get rid of them.

Something like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId></groupId>
  <artifactId></artifactId>
  <version></version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <exclude>**/xml/*</exclude>
    </exclusion>
    ...
```

This is what I want to use as a dependency:
[Jira Func Tests](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-func-tests/6.1.4)

The folder with XMLs is in the compiled jar in META-INF/lib/jira-func-tests-6.4.6.jar/XML
Before compilation, the XML folder is in resources folder of the jira-func-tests I guess?

Comment: Really `META-INF/lib`? This project is a `war` project?

Comment: Show where is **/XML/* in project structure file before compilation , and packaging application (war, jar , ear..) ?

Answer (score 1):

those XML files have to be "attached to something". Here is an example what usualy works and should work even in maven-2. So finding connections between those XML files and groupIDs and artifactIDs.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.15</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```